# Python string iteration

Tags: python, string

I am stuck, need check if string like '3456', or like '5678' is ladder like.
for example: 1234 - ladder

3476 - not ladder;

my code:

```
def is_ladder(block):
    for i in range(len(block)-1):
        if ( ord(block[i]) == ord(block[i+1])+1):           
            return True
    return False
```

how to realize? Also if possible, how to check if each char is same in string, like 'aaaa' or '5555'?

Comment: why do you think your code is not working?

Comment: because, output isn't what I want, there goes 5698, 3459. I need function to return TRUE, if 'xxxx' same chars as argument sent.

Comment: I think you meant `int()`, not `ord()`. Don't go mucking with the encoding values for characters, when you mean "the numerical value of this decimal digit".

Comment: what should be returned for '4321'?

Comment: for 4321, should return also true

Comment: Should '8642' also return true or just strings that increment or decrement by 1?

Comment: 8642 - should return False. True if, each char in string are decremented, or incremented by 1. Ex: 1234, 4567, 7654, 4321

Comment: So is '3434' True, or once you start decrementing/incrementing you always have to decrement/increment?

Comment: 3434 - false. once incremented, always incremented.

Comment: In c++ i think would be like this:
for(int i = 0; i < len-1; i++)
    if(str[i] == str[i+1]-1)
        return true
and for decrement similiar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def seq(s):
    if all(s[0]==x for x in s[1:]):
        return True
    elif ord(s[0]) > ord(s[1]):
        s = s[::-1]
    first = ord(s[0])
    for i in s[1:]:
        if ord(i) != first + 1:
            return False
        else:
            first = ord(i)
    return True
In [19]: seq("aaaa")
Out[19]: True

In [20]: seq("4321")
Out[20]: True

In [21]: seq("1230")
Out[21]: False

In [22]: seq("edcb")
Out[22]: True
```

Comment: Thank for additional solve for 'xxxx' where x - same char. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the new requirements, here:

```
 def is_ladder(block):
    step = ord(block[0])-ord(block[1])
    if step not in (-1,1):
        return False
    return all([ord(block[i])-ord(block[i+1])==step for i in xrange(len(block)-1)])
```

Can also check to see if every character is the same with:

```
block.count(block[0]) == len(block)
```

Comment: and how I can use it in my function?

Comment: You'd just return the result. I used your variable name so you can paste it in.

Comment: Also works great! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Check ordering up and down, after first converting to list of digits. Pairwise iteration lifted from https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes.

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pair(series):
    a, b = tee(series)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

def is_ladder(block):
    block_digits = [ord(c) for c in block]
    return (
        all(c + 1 == d for c, d in pair(block_digits)) or
        all(c - 1 == d for c, d in pair(block_digits))
    )
```

Results:

```
>>> print is_ladder('1234')
True
>>> print is_ladder('4321')
True
```

---

Later: here is the solution to your modified question (a ladder is all letters/digits the same).

```
def is_ladder(block):
    block_digits = [ord(c) for c in block]
    return (
        all(c + 1 == d for c, d in pair(block_digits)) or
        all(c - 1 == d for c, d in pair(block_digits)) or
        len(set(block_digits)) == 1
    )
```

---

And later still. If nothing else, it is useful to know the pairwise iteration idiom. Here is what it produces:

```
>>> for i, j in pair(range(5)):
...     print i, j
... 
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

It splits your sequence into pairs of consecutive elements. Iteration terminates when the second sequence (which was advanced one position by `next(b, None)`) is empty.